# ForkJoinPool process Arraylist and return two arrays

Tags: java, forkjoinpool

i have a huge List<String[]> like about 500k elements
validation of it takes too long - 35-40 sec
validation looks like this

```
   Iterator<String[]>iterator=parser.iterate(request.getInputStream()).iterator();
    List<String[]> list =new ArrayList<>();
    List<NotValidRow>badList=new ArrayList<>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
      var tmp=iterator.next();
      if(tmp.length!=2)continue;
      if (tmp[0] == null || !SKIP_PATTERN.matcher(tmp[0]).matches()) {
        badList.add(new NotValidRow(tmp[0], tmp[1], NotValidRowReason.NOT_VALID_EMAIL));
      }
      if(tmp[1]==null || tmp[1].isBlank()){
        badList.add(new NotValidRow(tmp[0],tmp[1],NotValidRowReason.EMPTY_NAME));
      }
      list.add(tmp);
    }
```

i think its possible to do it faster with fork join pool but i dnt know how to do it, could you guys help me wtih that

Comment: Your time is probably spent on reading/parsing the input stream sequentially, unless `SKIP_PATTERN` is really complicated. Could you check how long it takes if you skip the validation?

Comment: You could perhaps do some code profiling for `request.getInputStream()` just to see how long it takes to read the bytes, and then compare that with total processing time. Perhaps the input stream is fast, and most of the processing time is in your code, but.. my intuition is that akarnokd is correct. I would bet most of the time is spent on reading the input stream, not in the rest of your code. If that is indeed the case, any kind of parallel processing won't speed things up.

Comment: thanks for answer , parsing takes less than 2 secs

Comment: Can't you use parallel Streams (Java 8)? That should split up the validation into several parallel task using ForkJoinThreadPool.

Comment: i can , but do not know how to do it , i should return 2 lists with good emails and second one with not valid emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Stream` parallel processing, however, you'll have to sneak out the bad list in a thread-safe manner: for example:

```java
var spliterator = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0);

var badQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<NotValidRow>();

List<String[]> list = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, true)
    .filter(tmp -> {
        if (tmp.length != 2) {
            return false;
        }
        if (tmp[0] == null || !SKIP_PATTERN.matcher(tmp[0]).matches()) {
            badQueue.offer(new NotValidRow(tmp[0], tmp[1], NotValidRowReason.NOT_VALID_EMAIL));
            return false;
        }
        if (tmp[1] == null || tmp[1].isBlank()){
            badQueue.offer(new NotValidRow(tmp[0], tmp[1], NotValidRowReason.EMPTY_NAME));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
    .toList();

List<NotValidRow> badList = new ArrayList<>(badQueue);
```

**Edit** Apparently, the OP didn't mean to include the bad entries in the good list, so I've updated the answer to filter out the bad entries.

Comment: in your solution good list still contains good and bad rows, but i need separate good to good list and bad to bad list, else parallelstream make it faster for only 10 secs - without parrallel it take 39-40 sec , with parrallel -30 sec

Comment: @JD_UA this answer returns the same thing as your own solution. It's your own solution that has the problem you state here, i.e. good list includes the bad rows. If you wanted an answer that gives different results to what you have, you should have stated that in your question.

Comment: Indeed the original question's behavior looked odd, but thought the OP knows what they want to do. Updated the answer based on the new information.